# Are there SDK/UXSDK commands that perform go to operation similar to that DJI's GO 4

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I've been using these DJI Android Demos

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-UXSDKDemo

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio

with a Samsung Galaxy tablet and a Mavic 2 Zoom.

I want to mimic the behavior like DJI's GOTO capability in their GO 4 app. Preferably, the behavior I'd like to perform is when tapping the screen (camera view on the Android tablet) the  camera points to that spot.  then I wish to have a popup menu that allows selection of zooming in/out a specified amount. What would be the api calls to do this?

Thanks...

I've tried a couple of different DJI Mobile (Android) SDK Demos (links are in the problem description) and have gotten them to work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing Tap to Fly.

There is a mission type for this in the SDK but the is no short for any mission types in the UXSDK, you would need to create UI from scratch.

The UXSDK is really only intended to provide stock controlled for cameras and drone reporting and setup.  No IOC modes are included in the UXSDK.